# bloqueado en mi primer programa en python

Tags: python

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en python. En el curso nos piden un programa en el que el usuario tiene tres oportunidades para introducir una contraseña, dando igual las minusculas y las mayusculas.
estoy tremendamente atascado en las tres opprtunidades y en las mayusculas, minusculas.
me encantaria que alguien me ayudase, explicandome la respuesta, para poder aprender.
de momento he escrito esto

```
contraseña = "condicional"
respuesta = input("introduzca su clave: ")

for i in range (0,1,2):
    if respuesta == contraseña:
        print ("contraseña correcta", respuesta )
    else:
        print ("contraseña incorrecta", respuesta)
        respuesta = input("introduzca su clave: ")
        if respuesta == contraseña:
            print ("contraseña correcta", respuesta )
        else:
            print ("contraseña incorrecta", respuesta)
            respuesta = input("introduzca su clave: ")
            if respuesta == contraseña:
                print ("contraseña correcta", respuesta )
            else:
                print ("contraseña incorrecta", respuesta)
```

Comment: Lo de las mayúsculas y minúsculas es sencillo. Basta que uses `respuesta.lower()` para convertir a minúsculas la entrada del usuario y así compararla con la contraseña, que ya está en minúsculas. Lo de las tres oportunidades... para eso son los bucles, para evitar que tengas que repetir el código. Dentro del bucle pides la contraseña, la comparas con la buena y si son iguales **sales** del bucle (conoces la sentencia `break`?) Mientras no sean iguales se seguirá repitiendo el bucle por lo que automáticamente se pedirá otra vez.

Comment: Cuando el bucle se haya repetido tres veces, terminará. Puedes usar una variable booleana inicialmente a `False` para indicar si acertó la contraseña o no (la pondrías a `True` cuando la acierte). Así, una vez el bucle finalice, mirando esa variable podrás saber si finalizó porque acertó la contraseña, o porque la falló tres veces

Comment: Te dejo que pienses sobre lo que acabo de comentar y que lo intentes. Si te atascas de nuevo, edita tu pregunta para indicar lo nuevo que hayas avanzado y cuál es la nueva duda.

Comment: Repasa la función `range`. Tiene tres parametros: start, end, step. La iteración parte en `start` y en cada ciclo avanza `step` hasta que el valor generado sea igual o mayor a `end`. En `for i in range(0,1,2)`, solo itera una vez, con `i = 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

este es el programa quew he hecho

```
clave="condicional"
respuesta=(input("ingrese su clave: ")).lower
cont =0
while clave!=respuesta and cont <3:
        print('respuesta erronea: ', respuesta)
        respuesta=input ("introduzca su clave: ")
        cont +=1

if clave == respuesta:
     print('respuesta correcta: ', respuesta)
```

Comment: ¿es esto una respuesta? Quiero decir, ¿resuelve el problema? ¿O se trata de una ampliación de información sobre la pregunta? Si es lo segundo, por favor bórralo de aquí y ponlo en la propia pregunta (tiene un enlace "editar") y en ese caso aclara también si este código no funciona o qué preguntas sobre él.

Answer (score 0):

```
contraseña = "condicional"

respuesta = input("introduzca su clave: ")
if contraseña.upper()==respuesta.upper():
    print ("contraseña correcta", respuesta )
else:
    print ("contraseña incorrecta", respuesta) 
    for i in range(2):
        respuesta = input("Introduzca su clave: ")
        if contraseña.upper()==respuesta.upper():
            print ("contraseña correcta", respuesta )
            break
        else: print ("contraseña incorrecta", respuesta)
```

En este codigo se hace en primer lugar, comprobar si en el primer intento el usuario aserta en la contraseña, esto se comprueba con un if, la funcion .upper() hace que la palabra tenga todas las letras en mayuscula, asi da igual si pones minusculas o mayusculas, siempre se va a comparar las frases entre mayusculas. Si el usuario no asierta en el primer intento, se inicia un for loop con 2 iteracion ya que son los intentos restante que le quedan al usuario.

Comment: Tu respuesta contiene bastantes líneas iguales (como la del input o la comparación con la clave o los print de correcto/incorrecto). La repetición de código suele ser un indicio de que se puede hacer mejor. De hecho se puede escribir de modo que el input y la comparación aparezcan una sola vez, así como cada print. No he querido darle la solución aún al OP para ayudarle a pensar, puesto que dice que está aprendiendo.

Comment: Si, reduce el código para que no tenga repeticiones.

Answer (score 0):

Para llevar la cuenta de las repeticiones usamos la variable `intentos`, que parte en 3. Cuando llega a cero, significa que se hicieron tres intentos fallidos. Un valor distinto de cero señala que se ingresó la contraseña correcta.

Controlamos el ciclo comparando la respuesta ingresada contra la contraseña guardada. Inicializamos `respuesta` con `None` para garantizar que sea distinta de cualquier contraseña válida.

Al salir del `while`, el valor de `intentos` nos dirá si se ingresó la contraseña válida.

```
contraseña = "condicional"
respuesta = None
intentos = 3
while intentos and respuesta != contraseña:
    respuesta = input("introduzca su clave: ").lower()
    if respuesta != contraseña:
        print ("contraseña incorrecta", respuesta)
        intentos -= 1

if intentos:
    print("contraseña correcta", respuesta)
```

Answer (score 0):

La forma más compacta que puedes hacer:

```
contraseña = "condicional"
for i in range(3):
    respuesta = input("Introduce contraseña: ")
    if respuesta.lower() == contraseña.lower():
        print("Contraseña correcta")
        break
    else:
        print("Contraseña incorrecta:", respuesta)
```